# On the finite algebra $\Bbb F_q[X]_{<n}$ over $\Bbb F_q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, finite-fields, algebras

Let us take the vector space of all the polynomials of degree less than $n$ over the finite field $\Bbb F_q$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Bbb F_q[X]_{<n} &:=& \{ f(X)\in \Bbb F_q[X]:\deg f(X) <n\} \leq \Bbb F_q[X].
\end{eqnarray*}

Clearly, this is not a ring under the usual multiplication of polynomials. On the other hand, let us endow the abelian group $(\Bbb F_q[X]_{<n},+)$ with the following multiplication:
\begin{align*}
\odot: \Bbb F_q[X]_{<n}\times \Bbb F_q[X]_{<n} \longrightarrow \Bbb F_q[X]_{<n},\quad (f(X),g(X))\longmapsto f(X)\odot g(X):=r(X),
\end{align*}
where $r(X)\in \Bbb F_q[X]$ is the  remainder of the polynomial $f(X)g(X)\in \Bbb F_q[X]$, when divided by $X^n-1$.
This multiplication is known as **multiplication modulo** $\boldsymbol{ X^n-1}$. Then, $(\Bbb F_q[X]_{<n},+,\odot)$ forms a commutative ring with $1_{\Bbb F_q[X]_{<n}}\in \Bbb F_q[X]_{<n}$.

But I stack on the rest of the properties in order to show the algebra structure.

So, please let me expose my thoughts. For the associativity of $\odot$,
\begin{equation}
(f(X)\odot g(X))\odot h(X)=f(X)\odot (g(X)\odot h(X)) \tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
my thought is to apply the Division Algorigthm. That is, by dividing $f(X)g(X)$ by $X^n-1$, there exists unique $q(X),r(X)\in \Bbb F_q[X]$ such that $f(X)g(X)=(X^n-1)q(X)+r(X)$, where $r(X)=0$ or $\deg r(X)<n$. Thus, $f(X)\odot g(X)=r(X)$. Then, $(f(X)\odot g(X))\odot h(X)=r(X)\odot h(X)$. Thus, in the same spirit, there exists $q'(X),r'(X)\in \Bbb F_q[X]$ such that
$r(X)h(X)=q'(X)(X^n-1)+r'(X)$, where $r'(X)=0$ or $\deg r'(X)<n$. Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
(f(X)\odot g(X))\odot h(X) &=& r'(X) \\
&=& r(X)h(X)-q'(X)(X^n-1) \\
&=& (f(X)g(X)-(X^n-1)q(X))h(X)-q'(X)(X^n-1)\\ 
&=& f(X)g(X)h(X)-(X^n-1)q(X)h(X)-q'(X)(X^n-1)\\ 
&=& f(X)g(X)h(X)-(X^n-1)(q(X)h(X)+q'(X)).
\end{eqnarray*}
The latter is of degree $<n$ and as we can see it is the remainder of the division of $f(X)g(X)h(X)$ by $X^n-1$, and it is unique. By working likewise in the RHS of $(*)$, we obtain the same result. Hence the equality holds.

Is that argument complete and correct? Do we work likewise for the rest axioms and, furthermore, is there any faster way?

Comment: Professor, thank you for your comment. Could you please let me know that do I miss? I found this result here: https://users.math.msu.edu/users/halljo/classes/codenotes/PolyAlg.pdf (Lemma A.2.13).

Comment: I misinterpreted.  It may be okay.

Comment: @Randall For the compatibility of the two operations (that is $(\lambda f(X))\odot g(X)=f(X)\odot (\lambda g(X))=\lambda (f(X)\odot g(X))$, could we use the same argument? That is, $(\lambda f(X))\odot g(X)=\lambda f(X)g(X)-q(X)(X^n-1)$ and $f(X)\lambda g(X)-(X^n-1)q'(X)=f(X)\odot (\lambda g(X))$ are the same?

Comment: I can't see a reason for downvoting my question. Please let me know why.

Comment: Downvoting may be a bit harsh. But, trust me, no one with any algebra background (including coding theorists) would denote this algebra $\Bbb{F}_q[x]_{<n}$. Everybody would write it $\Bbb{F}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$. This is because the elements of **every** quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_q[x]/(p(x))$ with **any** degree $n$ polynomial $p(x)$ instead of $x^n-1$ gives a finite algebra with unique coset representatives of degree $<n$. Only the multiplication rule will be different. It may be overkill to say that whoever cooked up this notation should lose their algebra license, but....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your comment. I found this notation on J. Hall's notes (which I linked in the comments above). He actually mentions the commutative ring $F[x] \bmod m(x) $ in the chapter of cyclic codes. I believed this notation was fine instead of the identical (due to algebras isomorphism) quotient ring, since  we need the ideals of the former. And it is easier to manipulate the ideals of the former than the latter. Any suggestion for further reading is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster way.  I think it is worth learning about quotients of rings by ideals.  In your case, there is an isomorphism* of $\mathbb{F}_q[X]_{<n}$ and the quotient ring $\mathbb{F}_q[X]/I$ where $I$ is the principal ideal generated by $x^n$.  The general theory then tells you immediately (just from coset business) that $\mathbb{F}_q[X]/I$ is a commutative ring with identity because the "mother" $\mathbb{F}_q[X]$ is.  This way you can avoid checking all the axioms and put all the work on the abstract quotient ring construction.

*The correspondence is that the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} \in  \mathbb{F}_q[X]_{<n}$ maps to the coset $a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}  + I$.

Comment: Dear Randall, thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I wanted to show: $$\Bbb F_q[X]/I\cong \Bbb F_q[X]_{<n}$$
as algebras over $\Bbb F_q$ and the isomorphism is precisely the correspondence you mentioned. So, that's the reason I'm struggling to prove the algebra structure.

Comment: I understand.  Then yes, if you need $\mathbb{F}_q[X]_{< n}$ to be a ring as a birth-right, then you will have to check the axioms explicitly.

Comment: Yes, it is useful in Cyclic Codes, in Coding Theory. Could you please check if my argument holds?

Comment: Yes, your argument is right:  you have to make use of uniqueness of remainders.

Comment: @ Randall Many thanks Professor.